# phpMyAdmin, store procedure don't work as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I wrote a simple (test) procedure and it returns only 1 row, why is that?

```
SELECT *
FROM service
```

The procedure executes fine, just the result shown contains only first row instead of all table records.

Comment: because the table `service` has only 1 row.

Comment: Could you show us more part of the code?@user1973900

Comment: no, the table contains 9 rows. When I execute from SQL tab it returns all right

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 8 ( 9 total, Query took 0.0006 sec)
SELECT * 
FROM  `service` 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: @Shahriar there is no other code, I just test the stored procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got the last row each time. Then may be your code is something like that,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $user=$row['Username'];  //assume you have a column named Username
}

echo $user . "<br>";
```

But it should be like below, then you can get all data.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $user=$row['Username'];  //assume you have a column named Username
  echo $user . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for tips but I'm NOT using any code, from php or anything like. I just test from phpMyAdmin

Comment: Well, the problem is PhpMyAdmin software, I use 3.5.1 from Wamp server. The stored procedure returns just ONE row instead of all table contents. I just stored a complex SELECT with several LEFT JOINs which executes like a charm from inside .NET VB. Thanks @Shahriar for effort,c i'll give you my votes :) and I give up with PhpMyAdmin. Cheers all,

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just solve'it by accident :) Hope someone will need someday:

After creating the procedure, the "Execute" icon from "Routines" tab in phpMyAdmin is just NOT working, returning only 1 record from table. I downloaded the last 3.5.5 version and the problem is the same.

Actually, the procedure itself is working excellent, just use SQL tab and call it by hand writing:

```
call myProcedure
```

That's all folks :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Call the procedure from SQL window and it will work fine

Comment: I'm having the same problem and when I say "call myprocedure" it works fine, just like yours. It's kind of annoying, as it's easier to click the execute button, but at least there's a workaround until phpmyadmin gets updated in the YUM package. Thanks for this topic/answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test procedure did the `commit`.

Depending on *how* you run your MySQL statements you may or may not have an implicit `commit`. Phpmyadmin does this implicit `commit`. But if your test procedure is run through some other mean, such as a programming language like PHP, it is possible that you do not have `autocommit` set. Then your test procedure has to issue the `commit` statement itself to have the effect of the test appear to the rest of the world… And to Phpmyadmin.

Comment: please explain, I just save the procedure as I wrote in SQL tab, should I do other things to work?

Comment: @user1973900 Edited to provide more detail.

Comment: @kmkaplan thanks very much for your explanation and forgive my miss understanding. I just checked and autocommit is ON so I just don't get'it. As I stated above, the procedure executes perfectlly from within .NET so I guess phpMyAdmin has problems :) Never mind, I'm glad is working from my dev tool, phpMyAdmin was just for quick tests and probably I can live without this feature